# How to factorise integers using mysql

Tags: mysql, math

While doing my project i need to find the prime factorisation of an integer using mysql which i think is the efficient way for query beside doing all recursive thing.

and I want to achieve is to find the prime numbers composing an integer.

example: for *102*, the factorial numbers would be: *17*, *3*, *2*

Thank you.

Comment: Factoring a number is a famously hard problem; it underlies the security of many cryptographic algorithms. Why do you need to do this, and why do you need to do it in MySQL?

Comment: i think it will save the execution time than doing all that recursive thing

Comment: What is the range of the (input) integers that you might wish to factorise?

Comment: currently i am thinking about 4-6 digit

Comment: @SundeszKumarHyoju what do you mean with "it will save the execution time"?

Comment: beside geting the reverse factor using php function if there is any function we could use directly in mysql than i guess i will save some execution time

Comment: If you want to rapidly factorise any number up to 10^6 and are willing to trade space for time, I'd suggest building a simple lookup table of `(integer,factors)` indexed on `integer`.  With only a million rows, lookups should be extremely fast.  Populating the `factors` in that table is, of course, another matter...

Comment: You could write a stored procedure, yes, but why would you want your database to solve such a computionally expensive problem? That's a *database*, it exists to store data.

Comment: But factorising the numbers from 1 to 10^6 (or even 10^8) is also extremely fast in a programming language supporting arrays and primitive number types. Sieve for the smallest prime factor, then you can for each number recursively look up  the others.

Comment: However, for numbers below 10^6, simple trial division is so fast, it may be faster than a database query.

Comment: mysql takes more time in do mathematical operations than a programming language. As @Kos say, Mysql its a database

Comment: would you please tell us your use case? I cannot imagine a scenario where you would ever need this...

Answer (score 1):

back of envelope strategy (still requires programmed loop for step 2)

1. create table "primes" with single int column (primary key)
2. run this loop:

   ```
   for $x = 2 to $n {
     execute("
       insert into primes (id) 
       select $x where not exists 
        (select * from primes as p where p.id <= sqrt($x) AND ($x mod p.id) > 0)")
   }
   ```
3. use the subquery above to list your results for a specific $x

this solution will work for values to $n^2. Step 2 could be improved by only testing numbers over 9 with last digits 1,3,7,9.